# How to Enable Change Password at Next Logon for AD Users when Resetting password from Powershell

Tags: powershell, shell

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Identity,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$NewPassword
)

$adminUsername = 'username'
$adminPassword = 'Password'
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminUsername, ($adminPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

# Set the new password for the user account
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Identity -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $NewPassword -Force) -Credential $credential

# Enable the "User must change password at next logon" option for the user
Set-ADUser -Identity $Identity -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

# Create a custom object with the updated values
$outputObject = [pscustomobject]@{
Identity = $Identity
NewPassword = $NewPassword
}

# Convert the object to JSON and output it
$outputObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1
```

this is my powershell, it is resetting the password but when i login with the new password it doesn't ask me to change the password

Comment: ChangePasswordAtLogon is a switch, so try `-ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true`

Comment: @Theo, ChangePasswordAtLogon is Boolean; see https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser

Comment: @Mike B, have you checked using Active Directory Users and Computers that checkbox requiring user to change password is actually set to "enabled" after you run your script?

Comment: @MikeSh Yes, that seems to be an error in the description. Just try it as I commented; for me that works.  Also, make sure the `PasswordNotRequired` is set to false on that user:  `Set-ADUser -Identity $Identity -PasswordNotRequired:$false -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true` (and yes, the PasswordNotRequired is also a switch and not a Boolean as in the description..). You may even need to add `-CannotChangePassword:$false`

Comment: I just tested `Set-ADUser -Identity test -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true` works as expected. And `PasswordNeverExpires` attribute must not be enabled for the user